# How to add a bone to an already animated armature, to deform a curve?

Tags: armature

I know it has something to do with hooks but I can't control the curve with it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello, maybe give a bit more details, in Edit mode you can add bones, and to hook you need to select the bone in Edit or Pose mode, switch back to Object mode, shift select the curve, switch to Edit mode, select the curve vertex you want, press Ctrl H > Hook to Selected Bone

Comment: thanks a lot , i wanted to add a bone to an existing animated armature and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you want to add bones to an exisitng armature, or "stick" separate armature to another one.

In first case, in edit mode you can:

- subdivide existing bones - click rmb on the bone and choose subdivide
- grow new one from exisitng - select on of the bones in armature and press "E"
- duplicate one of the exisitng ones - select one and press shift+D

If you want to connect armature to another one, so it will follow it animation then:

1. select armature you want to attach to
2. change to edit mode, select bone wihch movement you want your additional armature to follow
3. change to object mode
4. select aramture you want to attach
5. with shift select armature you want to attach to
6. press ctrl+P and from pop up menu choose "bone" - it will then use the bone you selected in edit mode as the one which transfomrations new armature will follow